# leaflet draw plugin to edit features store in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, leaflet, geojson

I'm using Leaflet Draw Plugin and its working fine. Actually I'm trying to edit features based on there selection from a drop drown. So what I do is When I add geojson Layer `onEachFeature` I add each feature into an array and now selecting a feature from drop down I pass a member of array to Feature group to edit. But the problem here is, it generates error. Here is my code:

```
success: function (data) {
    cities = L.geoJson(data, {
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            var features[];
            features.push(layer);
        }
    }).addTo(map);
}
```

Now on selecting feature from drop down when I pass a member of array to feature group it throws an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'previousOptions' of undefined
```